# Как оперировать динамически загруженными данными?

Tags: javascript, php

Есть форма, в которой я вношу данные в таблицу бд. С этим проблем нет. На выходе я генерирую таблицу с введёнными данными и обновляю через ajax только один блок div, в котором содержится эта таблица. Хотел сделать кнопку для удаления одной из строк в таблице. Когда DOM документ загружен обычным способом - проблем нет. Когда удаляю данные, полученные динамически с помощью ajax, то срабатывает только при первом использовании. При втором передаются пустые заголовки, и соответственно, таблица просто исчезает до перезагрузки страницы.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button[id="item_delete"]',function() {
let $row = $(this).closest('tr');
let data = $row.find('input').serialize();
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete_item.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(html){
          $("#table_ajax").load('table.php');
          $('#order')[0].reset();
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Это load.php:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM currents WHERE set = '$bis' ORDER BY id";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$user = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$message = '<tr>';
foreach ($user as $users) {
$message .= '<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="' . $users['id'] . '">
<td>' . $users['item_name'] . '</td>
<td>' . $users['quantity'] . '</td>
<td><button type="submit" name="delete_item" id="item_delete" class="close" aria-label="Close" value="' . $users['id'] . '" data-toggle="tooltip"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></td>
</tr>';
}
echo $message;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже неправильно составляются строки таблицы, input должен быть внутри тега td

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM currents WHERE set = '$bis' ORDER BY id";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$user = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$message = '';
foreach ($user as $users) {
    $message .= '<tr>
        <td>' . $users['item_name'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $users['quantity'] . '</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" name="delete_item" class="close item_delete" aria-label="Close" value="' . $users['id'] . '" data-toggle="tooltip"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="' . $users['id'] . '">
        </td>
        </tr>';
}
echo $message;
```

Так же не используйте id если элементов с таким id планируется несколько на странице

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.item_delete', function() {
});
```